# In-App Purchase Product Ids not showing up in AppStoreConnect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

In-App Purchase Product Ids not showing up in AppStoreConnect Account. Even though I had create four Product Ids and they were approved and live. Also I am able to see all In-App purchase in App Store under my application name. I am also able to process In-App Purchase through live application. Its strange, that in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com under In-App Purchases section, there is no In-App purchase listed. Although all In-App purchases there few days back.

**Section under AppStoreConnect**
[image]

**Its appearing in App Store and I am able to purchase content successfully**
[image]

Need guidance if anything missing at my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Product Ids. It seems placement of **Non-Renewing Subscriptions** recently changed in AppStoreConnect.

I found Product Ids under this hierarchy:

```
App Store -> Features -> Subscriptions -> Non-Renewing Subscriptions -> Manage
```

[image]

Comment: I also had the same problem. Now able to see it under Subscriptions. You saved my day. Thanks.